# grub not showing in boot

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows-7, ubuntu-mate

I have a tri-boot computer (Ubuntu Mate 16.04.3LTS, Windows 7, Kali Linux). Until recently, grub menu showed at every boot just fine. However, tonight, I decided to exit Windows and load Ubuntu; I noticed that the grub menu never showed up and it just loaded automatically into Ubuntu. At first, I didn't think anything of it, because that's where I wanted. But now I can't get back into Windows.

I have tried:

- holding the shift key during boot
- running grub-update
- interrupting the boot process with ctrl+alt+delete
- performing boot-repair (log available at http://paste.ubuntu.com/26269885)
- and changed the etc/default/grub line25 by deleting the '#' from front of          line "GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480" (and running grub-update again)

I don't know if this is related but i also noticed that when I reboot my computer, the Dell logo doesn't show up on screen either

Answer (score 0):

Reading information on [pastebin](https://paste.ubuntu.com/26269885/),
I found out that

> GRUB_TIMEOUT=5

edit GRUB configutaion by running

> gksudo gedit /etc/default/grub

in terminal. Enter your root password, then edit

> GRUB_TIMEOUT=5

to

> GRUB_TIMEOUT=10

Save the configuration file and run

> sudo update-grub

This should solve your problem.

Comment: I'm not sure why the pastebin showed GRUB_TIMEOUT=5. I just checked that file and it says GRUB_TIMEOUT=10. And the problem still persists

Comment: Try increasing that number to say 30 seconds.

Comment: @TriciaYoung | Answer provided by  is same which I said, just it increases the timeout a bit more and uses GUI.
You are requested to please accept my answer too and upvote it.

Comment: Actually it wasn't the time with the GUI. In the GUI there was no check mark in show menu. And I had increased the time in that file, which still had not worked. Furthermore, it only worked that one time. I have, since, rebooted the computer again, and it no longer is working.

Comment: HAve you tried reinstalling GRUB

Answer (score 0):

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install grub-customizer

click On Grub-Customizer and follow this image:

http://www3.0zz0.com/2017/12/28/11/496874360.png

Comment: Update: It worked once. But I have since restarted, and now it is back to loading automatically to Linux, with no grub menu. I went back into the grub customizer, and all the settings are the same as they were before when it worked.

Comment: Do just as this picture :

Comment: http://www3.0zz0.com/2017/12/28/11/496874360.png